# About the use of future tense

Tags: word-choice, grammar, future, will-be-going

Which is better:

1. "I am not having lunch tomorrow unless I am really hungry."
2. "I am not having lunch tomorrow unless I will be really hungry."
3. Something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not having lunch tomorrow, unless I'm really hungry.

Is the correct answer. Present tense in the second sentence, because it's obvious you are not talking about the present, because you **already know** whether you are hungry now or not.

Also, try swapping them and you'll see it right away:

> Unless I'm really hungry, I am not having lunch tomorrow.

With the similar:

> If I'm not really hungry, I am not having lunch tomorrow.

You would **never** say either of those:

> Unless I will be really hungry, I am not having a lunch tomorrow.
>   If I won't be really hungry, I am not having lunch tomorrow.

Another examples to prove that present tense really expresses future condition:

> If I don't get the money, I'll be really angry.
>   If you fail the school exam, I won't give you your allowance!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. In spoken English, most people seem to use "lunch" instead of "a lunch", is the "a" for written English only ?

Comment: Uhm, I think you should better start another topic with this question. Not because I can't answer it here, but I really am not sure what's the difference between them, but I think I agree with what you said that they are both correct.

Comment: Thanks for your kind assistance, I'll follow your suggestion...

Comment: "having lunch" would be normal in UK English. Maybe a UK-US distinction?

Comment: @Neil Coffey thanks for your comment. It's good to know that the usage without "a" is common in UK. Thank you both for teaching me a lot today.

Comment: @Neil Coffey: "having lunch" would be normal in US English as well. If you were "having a lunch", you would possibly be hosting it.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of OP's suggestions are correct. Nor does @RiMMER's answer improve things by inserting the word **a**.

There are probably several better ways to phrase the statement, one of which is

**I will not** [or won't] **have lunch tomorrow unless I get really hungry.**

I'm not sure exactly how to explain what's wrong with the alternatives, but it's to do with using **I am** (present tense) when talking about something in the future. This is fine if that future is unquestionably expected to take place. But in this case the rest of the sentence casts serious doubt on whether it will in fact come to pass. It's inappropriate to use the present tense here because it implies that *at the time of speaking* the future being talked about is fully expected to arrive in due course.

Comment: @FumbleFinger, thanks for your comment. Your explanation has helped to clarify the discussion even more. Thanks!

Comment: +1: As FumbleFingers says, you don't put unless or if clauses in the future tense in English. If you want to express the future in such a clause, there are other ways of doing that. For example: *I won't be having lunch tomorrow unless I **get** really hungry.* For this sentence, the intended tense is clear, so you don't need to do that, but I'm sure you can come up with other examples which are more ambiguous.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Thanks for that. I only switched the *first* **I am**. I still didn't really like it, but I left the second one in because at least it wasn't totally wrong like OP's alternative **I will be**. Which is a common error, but sticks out like a sore thumb to native speakers. **Become**, and your much better **get** are more suited to talking about 'future' hunger. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: To clarify, the only truly ungrammatical part of the original question was *unless I will be really hungry,* which used the future tense in an *unless* clause. But a native English speaker would be quite a bit more likely to use FumbleFingers' improvement than the original.

Comment: Agreed. But we should tend to promote what the natives actually say, rather than what they don't say, but can't rule out on grammatical grounds.

Comment: I think people are reading far too much into this. Really, as far as I can see, sentence (1) is a perfectly grammatical sentence of English (although (2) is ungrammatical). If it was really this complicated talk about simple lunch plans, the human race would have gone extinct by now.

Comment: @Neil Coffey: Agreed (1) is grammatically acceptable, but I do feel it's 'at the margin', so to speak. Given OP is a non-native speaker who's not even clear that (2) *isn't* ok, I just feel it's better to steer him towards the more common forms. If you like, that's *underanalysis*, rather than nit-picking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I wonder if this is a UK/US difference, then? Really to me, (1) sounds a completely normal, usual sentence of English (I'm from the UK), perhaps just with the proviso that it's unusual not to contract "I am" to "I'm". In UK English, I don't believe there's any preference per se between "I'm not having..." vs "I won't have..."-- they just mean slightly different things ("won't" implies a more spontaneous decision; "I'm not having..." implies you've thought about it in advance).

Comment: @Neil Coffey: Well I'm UK too. Basically I agree with @Peter Shor re 'grammaticality', and he's US. But stylistically it really grates on me to see the present tense *twice* in an utterance which is not only talking about the future, but an explicitly uncertain future at that.