# "I am going to bed" vs. "I will be going to bed"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, present-tense, progressive-aspect, will-be-going

What is the difference between saying the following?

> I am going to bed in a few minutes.
>
> I will be going to bed in a few minutes.

Or

> I will be getting off here. Or, I guess, I will be getting off here. See you.
>
> I am getting off here. Or, I guess, I am getting off here. See you.

Which one seems more fluent and natural?

Comment: See [Differences between ways to express future actions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57053)

Comment: See [About the use of future tense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26514),

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: @jwpat7- None of the mentioned links answer my question. I have already had a look at the last link. If you look at the graph that they use for representation, *will be going to* and *am going to* have the same graph bar, which make it confusing.

Comment: usually you're lying. "I'm going to bed now" when you're still online. Current tense is the lie...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are fluent and natural, but they have different meanings.

**I am...** means that not only have you made the decision to go to bed *imminently* or get off the bus, but you are actively doing that — finishing off a drink or TV programme, or moving towards the bus doors.

**I will be...** means that you have made the decision to go to bed or get off the bus *soon* but you haven't actually done anything about it yet.

The import of each sentence is implicit in the tense used. **I am** is present tense and you are actually in the process of doing the action; **I will be** is future tense and although you know you will be doing something, you haven't started yet.

Comment: I am setting next to my friend on a bus and I tell my friend: I guess, I will getting off here, so see you next time. I haven't started standing yet, but I am preparing myself to get off as soon as the bus stops. Or I am just wrapping up my *talking*. So which one do you think makes more sense?

Comment: I would use *am* in that case, but it's a borderline example because you have made the decision to get off imminently (by using *here* rather than *at the next stop*) even though you haven't actually stood up yet.

Comment: But I had this specific bus stop in mind before I got on the bus.I knew that I would be getting off at this particular stop.

Comment: So? It's a question of imminence. *Here* indicates that you are very close to the stop, so *am* is appropriate because if you don't do something **now** you will miss your stop. If you are far enough away to say "at the next stop" then it's not imminent and *will be* is appropriate.

Comment: Aha, cool. So, it doesn't have to do anything with the stop that I had in mind while getting on the bus?

Comment: No: hopefully everyone knows where they will be getting off! You can say "I will be getting off at Marble Arch" (in a few stops' time) or -- even on the approach to Marble Arch --  "I'm getting off at Marble Arch" to indicate that it's happening now and you are not going to be dissuaded and miss the stop. It's all to do with time.

Comment: **Strongly disagree with this answer**!  One example that the OP posted was "I am going to bed in a few minutes".  That clearly does NOT mean "I am doing this now".  For the other example, if I buy a train ticket from a ticket office, I might be asked "where are you getting off" - when clearly I haven't even got on yet!

Comment: @DavidWallace: It indicates immediate intention, as comments may have clarified. The train of actions which result in going to bed have started (although they may finish in a few minutes). "I will be going to bed" means that you know you will start the train of actions soon.

Comment: @DavidWallace- Any thoughts? How would you describe it?

Comment: @Andrew Leach  I'm not going to discuss the imminence or just the intention of an action as per the various examples above, but I was under the impression that "I will be doing something" should be used when speaking of a future action which will require some time to be performed (thus the use of a continuous tense), for example "Tomorrow (at this time) I'll be having dinner with Fred". Am I right in this assumption?

Comment: @Paola, you are right that this is a common use of the future continuous. (Another example: *At this time tomorrow I'll be sitting in the plane on the way home.*) However, this is not the only use of this tense. It is also used to denote a planned future action and, as such is equivalent to the present continuous: *I'm seeing the boss at 10.30 tomorrow.* = *I'll be seeing the boss at 10.30 tomorrow.* It is also often used to soften questions. Instead of the direct: *Are coming to the meeting?*, you can ask more obliquely: *Will you be coming to the meeting?*

Comment: @Shoe Thanks, I think I have a better understanding of the usage now

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks which is more fluent and natural. As a native speaker (British), I would suggest that *will* sounds rather pedantic despite being technically correct. In most states of imminence I would normally expect *am* to be used.

Comment: Yes, and in normal conversation I'd expect that to be the contracted form: *I'm*.   *I'm getting off here- See ya later.*